# Количество новых заказов Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Доброе время суток
Хочу написать для себя модуль который показывает количество - заказов, новых клиентов,

Написал вид осталось подключить получение даных с базы
Код взял с модуля который показывает эти параметры в админ панели, но не могу понять как определить сегодняшнюю дату при получении даных с базы

```
    public function addData($params)
{

    $days = (strtotime($params['date_to']) - strtotime($params['date_from'])) / 3600 / 24;

        return array(
            'data_value' => array(
                'new_customers' => round(rand(1, 5) * $days),
            ),
        );
    
    Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

    $new_customers = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer`
        WHERE `date_add` BETWEEN "'.pSQL($params['date_to']).'" AND "'.pSQL($params['date_to']).'"
        '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_ORDER)
    );

    return array(
        'data_vaue' => array(
            'new_customers' => (int)$new_customers,
        )
    );
}
```

Модуль хочу чтоб был валидный на Prestashop 1.6 и 1.7

Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу

Может кому-то поможет - [вот результат](https://github.com/kliford/prestaModul)

код который был

```
    public function getValueConfiguration()
   {        
    $todayFrom = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
    $todayTo = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';

    $new_customers = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer`
        WHERE `date_add` BETWEEN "'.pSQL($todayFrom).'" AND "'.pSQL($todayTo).'"
        '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_ORDER)
    );

    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
            'client_value' => (int)Configuration::get('NEW_CLIENT', (int)Tools::getVAlue('NEW_CLIENT')),
            'new_customer' => $new_customers,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: 1. [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. 2. для ответа на вопрос «как определить сегодняшнюю дату при получении данных с базы» достаточно, вероятно, всего нескольких строчек текста и кода. приведите их, пожалуйста, в ответе.